# Algorithm to spread apart labels on a graph for better visualization

Tags: python, plot, visualization, matplotlib, scatter-plot

Basically, I want to make this graph look prettier.  You can see there are areas of extreme overdraw.  I could certainly abbreviate the names manually and shrink the font size, but I'd like some algorithm that pushes apart labels in overdrawn areas so their text is more readable.  I think this must be a well studied problem, I just don't know what it's called.

Already implemented solutions in Python would be great, but I'll settle for descriptions of techniques that tend to work in practice.

[image: Dominion projected card names]